# Placing interactive markers on joints of a robot model using Ros3djs

Tags: ros, ros3djs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to tele-operate a robot arm via interactive markers placed on each joint of the model displayed in a web page. I am planning to use ros3djs to address this task. I went through the tutorials mentioned in the package website. But, i cannot understand how to place markers on each joint of the robot arm.

How can i do this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251099/placing-interactive-markers-on-joints-of-a-robot-model-using-ros3djs/) by [Werewolf_86](https://answers.ros.org/users/28918/werewolf_86/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2017-01-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-02**:
This would appear to a duplicate of [Placing interactive markers on joints of a robot model using Ros3djs](http://answers.ros.org/question/251056). Can you please not post questions multiple times, it typically results in either both questions ignored, or duplication of effort.

**Comment by [Werewolf_86](https://answers.ros.org/users/28918/werewolf_86/) on 2017-01-02**:
Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I deleted the previous post. Would you be able to help me out regarding this problem ? Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this a ros3djs specific problem, i.e. do you have interactive markers working in RViz, but not ros3djs?

If you don't, you'll need a package that generates those markers first.

You can look to http://wiki.ros.org/cob_interactive_teleop or http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_interactive_markers/Tutorials/indigo/UsingTurtlebotInteractiveMarkers for inspiration on how to use interactive markers for teleoperation :)

---

Originally posted by [T045T](https://answers.ros.org/users/5420/t045t/) with karma: 48 on 2017-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0